# Selenium WindowHandels doesn't recognize modal window

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a site that opens a new (smaller) browser window, which I'm trying to test in Selenium.

I am using the ChromeWebDriver (2.27).

I have the following code:

```
String parentHandle = Driver.Instance.WindowHandles[0].ToString();
String modalHandel = Driver.Instance.WindowHandles[1].ToString();
```

I've tried several different variations (i.e. using ReadOnlyCollections & for loops) with the same result.

When I look at Driver.Instace.WindowHandles I see 2 entries.  The 1st one (I'm guessing) is my main window and the 2nd one is the modal.

[image]

However, about 50% of the time this code errors.

```
String modalHandel = Driver.Instance.WindowHandles[1].ToString();
```

Stating that:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

Maybe it is late in the day, but I really don't understand why this sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't.  Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be timing issue, the smaller browser might open after you are looking for its `WindowHandle` so `Driver.Instance.WindowHandles` contains only the parent `WindowHandle`. You can try to wait until there are two handles

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles;
while ((windowHandles = Driver.Instance.WindowHandles).Count < 2);

string parentHandle = windowHandles[0]; // its already string, no need to call ToString()
string modalHandel = windowHandles[1];
```

You can also limit the time

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles;
while ((windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles).Count < 2 && stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 10);

string parentHandle = windowHandles[0];
string modalHandel = windowHandles[1];
```

Comment: I did put a thread.sleep(250) right beforethe windoHandles code and it did appear to register the multiple values.  I will do the while statement in the AM and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: The Thread.Sleep(250) also worked on this but I like this better then a bunch of Thread.Sleep commands.